# program to convert/compile multiple .pdf's pulled from a database into one .pdf/text file/html

Tags: language-agnostic, text, automation

my friend works for the local government and he says his office waste a lot of time performing the process described in the title, that is:
1. querying a database for a name. the database in question is more ebscohost then a mysql.
2. individually removing text from a series of .pdfs.
3. pasting/outputting those results into a single file.

my limited background is in php, javascript, html, etc. and i just don't think they have the ability to read file types like that, correct me if i'm wrong. So i guess i"m just looking for 1. a language/or approach that might fit well with what i've already learned. 2. A description of how much of an undertaking this would be. I'm going to try get some more precise info from him and will add that when i get it. Also i don't have the requisite rep. to add '.pdf' to the tags, seems like it fits. thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.courts.mo.gov/casenet/base/welcome.do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be better tools but you could achieve your goal by combining two utilities:

1. Plain text extractor (for example Apache Tika) that will retrieve plain text contents from a pdf file
2. Converter from html to PDF (you create your target document in HTML and convert it into PDF when ready). One of such tools is wkhtmltopdf (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

First you extract the plain text from the input PDF files and then you create the output document in html, inserting the text retrieved from PDF into some kind of HTML template. Then you convert the html into a pdf file. This way you never have to touch the internals of pdf document, you're working only on plain text.